# Tuleap : How to save Bug tracker report configuration?

Tags: tuleap

I created a Bug Tracker and open different bugs. When I enter in my Bug Tracker, I see a web page with a search form in the upper part and a list with the different bugs in the lower part. However by default there are no information given for each bug. As I am administrator of my project I can configure the different informations given for each bug from the column widget on the right part of the web page. For example I can add Artifact ID, Submitted by, Severity, Summary, etc...

But if I register my report with the blue button "Enregistrer" I lose all my configuration and the bugs list display no column. What is wrong ? How can I save the different information I want to display for each bug of my list ?

Anyone have the solution ?

When i do "Save", i have the message "Bugs have been saved" but i lose all my configuration...

An other thing : the standard tracker templates of Tuleap are not available on my installation : i can't see this list to choose a template (Bugs, Change Requests, Empty, Tasks...).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe with your bug tracker report doesn't sound like the standard behaviour at all. You are doing everything right. I would log a bug on Tuleap's bug tracker.

The standard tracker templates should belong to the initial administration project. If you have removed the trackers from that project or have set restrictive rights on them then you can no-longer use them as templates.